# triggering replication in pouchdb, _rev comparaison

Tags: couchdb, replication, pouchdb

I replicate a couchdb base on a local pouchdb.
It does the job. After, I modify the local data, the changes are stored localy. Exactly what I want.

My problem is I want the changes in couchdb to get replicated to the local pouchdb when I reload the application. I found that it happens only when the _rev field in couchdb is greater than the _rev in pouchdb.

Is there a way to achieve my goal : replicate changes from couchdb, and beeing able to store local changes in pouchdb until there is a new version in couchdb?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how CouchDB replication works. The replication _is_ happening. The problem is that there is a conflict that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I have to handle this conflict manually, when couchdb has not the good _rev to wipe the old data...